# SSH into a system and browse the files in a particular folder using java

Tags: java, ssh

I am suppose to ssh into another system and browse the files in a particular folder. I am using JSch library to ssh into the system but I am not sure how to browse the files. I want the user  to navigate through the folders and select the file similar to JFileChooser. Please can anyone help me with this?

Regards,
Colin

Comment: Use [SFTP](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html) rather than plain SSH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. This is your best option:
   If you're client is able to mount a drive using ssh, mount the drive and simply give them the file chooser at that mount point.

Linux and Mac make it easy to mount ssh servers as a drive. On windows, you're gonna have to use third party tools. Whichever the case, you can then use command's to get the tool to mount the drive.

[here is how to mount ssh drives](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh)

[or you can use sftp. But I haven't had any success](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html)

2. If you just want the user to pick files from one specific directory and no where else; meaning no sub-dirs... etc

You can make your own gui and just show the content of that dir. You would know the content by simply doing a ls.

3. If you want any file on that system and possibly in nested directories

You can go through all of the files on the remote server using something like [this](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/) and re-render it to a gui on the clients side using something like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this would be to use java Runtime, example below

Process P = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command goes here");

you can pass your shell commands like `ls`, and use BufferedReader to read the stdout and do further processing.